# Nested query and insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a many-to-many relation between authors and publications. I have a separate authors table and I would like to insert the co-authors for every entry into that table.

So far, I can query the co-authors (including the author itself) for a fixed row (here the row with author_id=1) [updated with RosSQL's help]:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name 
FROM publication_authors pa
JOIN authors a
ON a.id = pa.author_id
WHERE pa.publication_id IN 
  (SELECT publication_id
  FROM publication_authors
  WHERE author_id=1)
;
```

I'm struggling to find the right syntax for combining the sub-query with the outer query. What i would basically like is a declarative way to express:

```
for id in authors:
  QUERY(id) // where id is substituted for 1
```

Furthermore it would be great to also have the year of the co-authorship available in the authors table, which is stored in a separate publication table.

My tables have the following columns:

Author: **id | name**

Publication: **id | name | year**

Authors/Publications: **id | id**

Author should become: **id | name | coauthor | year**

As stated below, a new table holding the co-author information would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "... like to insert the co-authors for every entry into that table." You should know that it is **best practice to have only one keeper-of-the-truth** in your database.  This is NOT the case when building a data warehouse.

A problem with your question is when you have more than one co-author.  This is entirely possible in a many-to-many relationship.

If you just want to produce the output in the format that you specified, then try:

```
select 
      pub.id
    , pub.name
    , stuff((SELECT ', ' + a.name 
        from publication_authors pa
        join Author a on a.id = pa.AuthorID
        WHERE pa.PublicationID = pub.id
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,' ') as Authors
    , pub.year_
from publication pub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as a beginner this went over my head, unfortunately. First off, I should have specified that I use PostgreSQL, so 'stuff' isn't available. I'm not sure if I can use string_agg instead. I would also be fine with putting the co-author information into a separate table.

Maybe I'm missing it, but I feel like there is a level of redirection missing to produce co-authors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the first two entries in the many-to-many table with the first as "Author" and the second as "coAuthor" then you can try:

```
select * 
        , (select top 1 a.name 
            from Author a 
            join publication_authors pa on pa.AuthorID = a.id
            join Publication pub_ on pub_.id = pa.PublicationID and pub_.id = PubID
            where a.name <> z.Author
            order by pa.id
            ) as CoAuthor
from (
    select 
          pub.id as PubID
        , pub.name
        , (select top 1 a.name 
            from Author a 
            join publication_authors pa on pa.AuthorID = a.id
            join Publication pub_ on pub_.id = pa.PublicationID and pub_.id = pub.id
            order by pa.id
            ) as Author
        , pub.year_
    from publication pub
    ) z
```

This will work in TSQL, you will have to try it yourself in PostgreSQL.  Perhaps next time you might tag with the PostgreSQL.